# i am finding it difficult to spawn an android device and interact with it programmatically

Tags: android, automated-tests, genymotion

Basically, I want to be able spawn an android device online through services such as genymotion cloud. But that is all I have been able to do with gmaas but I want to also be able to send commands to open a specified app and build a set of commands to do something within the app launched.

PS: i have done my research, its just that noone seems to want to go past authentication and sprawn a device. What i don't understand is how to feed the next page in their input boxes.

Any help will be appreciated even if all you have to give me is just an idea, I am certain that I can turn it into gold, i mean code.

Comment: Honestly there isn't enough detail here beyond use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) or perhaps by looking at something like [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) you can get a sense of what can be done over `adb`. I can't tell if the app you are trying to inject data into you have source code access or not. Also please spell things out like 'gmaas' which I think is Genymotion Software as a Service.

Comment: Thanks, I agree there isn't much detail in the question but you have pointed me in the right direction, that was all I needed. Thanks again.